# How many distinct matrices are there in $M_{m,n}(\mathbb{F}_2)$? How many are diagonal or upper triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

> How many distinct matrices are there in $M_{m,n}(\mathbb{F}_2)$? How many are diagonal or upper triangular?

**My thoughts:** 
I've found that there are $16$ such matrix when $m=n = 2$ by just listing them. So I'm guessing the answer is $2^{mn}$, since the case $m=3$ and $n=1$ also happens to give $8 = 2^{3 \cdot 1}.$

I thought of doing it by induction in the $m=n$ case, but couldn't make use of the induction hypothesis (see below). I also thought about there might be a counting argument to be applied to this, but I never studied combinatorics so I wouldn't know where to start. Thanks in advance.

**Attempt:**  I tried induction on the case $m=n$. Let $\mathcal{P}{(n)}$ be the statement that there are $2^{n^2}$ distinct matrices in $M_{n}(\mathbb{F}_2).$ If $n =2$ then we have $M_{n}(\mathbb{F}_2) = 2^{2\cdot 2},$ so our base case is true. Assume that $\mathcal{P}{(k)}$ is true, i.e. there are $2^{k^2}$ distinct matrices in $M_{k}(\mathbb{F}_2)$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. We wish to prove that $\mathcal{P}{(k+1)}$ is true, i.e. that for $M_{k+1}(\mathbb{F}_2)$ it is $  2^{(k+1)^2}$. If $E_{ij}$ are the canonical basis of $M_{n}(\mathbb{F}_2)$, we can write it as:

$$\displaystyle M_{k+1}(\mathbb{F}_2) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}a_{ij}E_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}a_{ij}E_{ij}+\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}a_{(k+1)j}E_{(k+1)j}+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_{i(k+1)}E_{i(k+1)}$$

I thought this gives $2^{k^2}\cdot 2^{k+1} \cdot 2^{k+1} \cdot 2^{-1} = 2^{(k+1)^2} $ distinct matrices where $2^{k^2}$ comes from the double sum because of the induction hypothesis, and the two $2^{k+1}$'s come from the separate sums indexed by $j$ and $i$ and the $2^{-1}$ comes from that we have fixed $E_{k+1,k+1}$ and $E_{k+1, k+1}$ for the sums.

Comment: Yes, surely we have $|M_{m,n}(K)|=|K|^{mn}$ for a (say finite) field $K$. We have $M_{m,n}(K)\cong K^{mn}$ as vector spaces over $K$. So no induction is needed. For counting matrices over finite fields see [here](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~svs/talks/2011/finitefield.pdf), for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Many thanks. I'm learning a lot from the article you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each entry of the matrix you have 2 choices (for a general finite field $\mathbb{K}$ there are $|\mathbb{K}|$ choices). You can make $mn$ such choices independently (for each entry), thus there are $2^{mn}$ such matrices ($|\mathbb{K}|^{mn}$ in general).

Comment: Many thanks. I've adopted your method to the second part of the question, and I've found that there are $2^n$ diagonal matrices and $2^{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)}$ triangular matrices in $M_{m,n}(\mathbb{F}_{2})$.